# add html in middle of parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

my code is

```
<div class="col-lg-6 stickyboard" style="padding:5px;">
    <div class="sticky-container" >
        <div class="sticky" >
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            {{content}}
        </div>
        // If click on this
        <i class="mdi-content-add pull-right" id="addNewSticky"></i>
    </div>
</div>
//Here I want to add some html
<div class="col-lg-6 stickyboard" style="padding:5px;">
    <div class="sticky-container" >
        <div class="sticky" >
            <h4>{{title}}</h4>
            {{content}}
        </div>
        <i class="mdi-content-add pull-right" id="addNewSticky"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks on addnewsticky I want to add html immediatly after that sticky,

**Expected output**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 stickyboard" style="padding:5px;">
        <div class="sticky-container" >
            <div class="sticky" >
                <h4>{{title}}</h4>
                {{content}}
            </div>
            // If click on this
            <i class="mdi-content-add pull-right" id="addNewSticky"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Hi this is added html</h3>
    <div class="col-lg-6 stickyboard" style="padding:5px;">
        <div class="sticky-container" >
            <div class="sticky" >
                <h4>{{title}}</h4>
                {{content}}
            </div>
            <i class="mdi-content-add pull-right" id="addNewSticky"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See  newly added html `<h3>` tag

How to do that using jquery?

```
addNewSticky:function(e,tmpl){
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().find('.stickyboard').html("some html");
    }
```

but this is adding to the same class itself not after that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert it after the `.stickyboard` ancestor of the click target.

So

```
$(e.currentTarget).closest('.stickyboard').after("<h3>Hi this is added html</h3>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .after() also like:

```
addNewSticky:function(e,tmpl){
        $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().after("some html");
    }
```